# Can't deploy Spring boot app on Jelastic

Tags: deployment, spring-boot, jelastic

I'm using Jelastic . It works great with my PHP and servlet apps. But when I deploy Spring boot apps it's not working at all, even for a simple spring boot apps. Didn't find any doc in this case. Can i get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intelio,
There are two ways to deploy Spring boot app on Jelastic:

1. By building it from your [Git/SVN repository using Maven](https://docs.jelastic.com/maven-cloud-hosting-in-jelastic/);
2. By deployment your WAR file directly to [Jelastic environment via archive/URL](https://docs.jelastic.com/upload-deploy-application/).

Please note that Spring Boot usage requires [Java 8](https://docs.jelastic.com/java-versions) at your application server.